# Get number of markers shown in Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am showing a list of n markers in a map, then I make zoom to my location and I would like to know if its possible to count just how many markers are displayed in my area.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify what kind of map and list you're using. If you store the markers in a normal list, just get the list size by using `int count = list.size();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call below method for each marker to see if they are inside the Maps visible area.

`map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())`

If the getBounds method is not available try this:

```
VisibleRegion region = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
LatLngBounds mapBound = region.latLngBounds;
int count 0;
for(Marker marker : makers) { // markers is the List of marker you have
  if(mapBound.contains(marker.getPosition()){
    count = count + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a List of marker  within your `Activity` or `Fragment` and then do a loop on it to see if its in the visible area `List.size()` to get the number of marker.

```
private List<Marker> mMarkerArray = new ArrayList<Marker>();


 ///to get number of marker 
 int marker_count = = 0; 
 for(int i =0;i<=mMarkerArray.size();i++){
     if(mMap.latLngBounds.contains(new LatLng(mMarkerArray.get(i).getLocation().getLongitude(), mMarkerArray.get(i).getLocation().getLatitude())){
  marker_count++;
  }
}
```

just make sure you add the marker in the list after you add it to your map object